# object(...) is not a function when publish angular 11 application

Tags: .net-5, angular11

I had application in angular 6 with .net core 2.1 and now I upgraded into 11 with .Net 5 and its works fine in my local system but when I published to Azure virtual machine at that time it is giving me below error, I already update necessary package like Angular CLI and .NET runtime at vitual machine so not sure why this error appear

[image]

here is my package.json

"dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "1.0.0",
"@angular/animations": "^11.2.8",
"@angular/cdk": "^11.2.7",
"@angular/common": "11.2.8",
"@angular/compiler": "11.2.8",
"@angular/core": "11.2.8",
"@angular/forms": "11.2.8",
"@angular/http": "7.2.16",
"@angular/localize": "^11.2.8",
"@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.8",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.8",
"@angular/router": "11.2.8",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.0",
"@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^5.0.0-beta.8",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
"@progress/telerik-angular-report-viewer": "^11.20.1021",
"@ryancavanaugh/jquery.prettyphoto": "^3.1.14-alpha",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
"@videogular/ngx-videogular": "^3.0.1",
"adal-angular4": "^3.0.16",
"angular-google-charts": "^0.1.6",
"angular-moment": "^1.3.0",
"angular-safeguard": "^2.1.0",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
"core-js": "^2.6.12",
"file-saver": "^2.0.5",
"flexslider": "^2.7.2",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"google-code-prettify": "^1.0.5",
"html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"jquery.easing": "^1.4.1",
"jspdf": "^2.3.1",
"jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.14",
"modernizr": "^3.11.6",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.32",
"ng-drag-drop": "5.0.0",
"ng2-pdfjs-viewer": "^5.0.7",
"ngx-material-timepicker": "^3.3.1",
"ngx-sortablejs": "^11.1.0",
"ngx-spinner": "^6.1.2",
"popper.js": "^1.16.1",
"primeflex": "^2.0.0",
"primeicons": "^1.0.0",
"primeng": "^11.3.1",
"rxjs": "^6.6.7",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
"sequencejs": "^2.0.0",
"sortablejs": "1.7.0",
"videogular2": "^7.0.2",
"xlsx": "^0.16.9",
"yarn": "^1.22.10",
"zone.js": "^0.10.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.6",
"@angular/cli": "^11.2.6",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.8",
"@angular/language-service": "11.2.8",
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.46",
"@types/flexslider": "0.0.2",
"@types/jasmine": "^2.8.17",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.5",
"@types/jspdf": "^1.3.3",
"@types/modernizr": "^3.5.3",
"@types/node": "^6.14.13",
"codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "^6.3.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.3",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "^7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~4.1.0",
"tslint": "~5.9.1",
"typescript": "4.1.5"
}

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an issue with one of your dependencies, which you should generally update alongside updating the framework.

I can see `"ngx-spinner": "^6.1.2"` in your `package.json` file, can you please check its version as well. It should be `11.0.2`, try to install that specific version and check again.